# What does it mean when there are gaps in historical stock aggregates (bars)?

Tags: stocks, stock-markets

For many less popular stocks, looking at historical data shows "gaps" for which there is no information.  For example, here are a couple days in March at 1-minute granularity for such a stock from Yahoo! Finance:

[image: Sparse historical data]

Why are there so few minutes represented on this chart?  Is data *missing* from this chart, or was there really no activity causing a change in price for the missing periods?

Comment: I *suspect* the answer is that there just isn't any activity in those periods, since you describe the stock as "less popular", but it's hard to say for sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Illiquid stocks often do not trade for long periods of time during the day.  If that's the case here then Yahoo is accurately reporting the trading pattern.  If not, then it's bad data.